# Integral de polinômios em scilab

Tags: scilab

Como fazer para descobrir a integral de uma expressão de polinômios em [scilab](/questions/tagged/scilab) ?

Tenho esse código:

```
clc;
clear;

x=poly(0,"x");
printf("Digite a expressão para calcular:");
 mfun=input("");
printf("MENU DE OPÇÕES\n");
printf("1-DERIVADA\n");
printf("2-INTEGRAL\n");
printf("3-MAX E MIN RELATIVOS\n");
printf("4-EXTREMOS\n");
printf("5-DOMINIO\n");
printf("6-IMAGEM\n");
printf("0-SAIR\n");
opcao=input("Digite um numero:");

    if(opcao==0) then
        printf("\nVocê optou por sair do programa!");
end
while(opcao<>0 )


select opcao




case 1 then
    if(i==0) then
       z=derivat(mfun);
       i=i+1;
   end
     if(i<>0)then 
         z=derivat(z);
         end
       disp(z);

    case 2 then
        printf("INTEGRAL");

    case 3 then
    printf("MAX MIN");

    case 4 then
    printf("EXTREMOS");


    case 5 then
        printf("DOMINIO");

    case 6 then
        printf("A imagem de sua função é: %d",opcao);





end
    printf("\n MENU DE OPÇÕES\n");
    printf("1-DERIVADA\n");
    printf("2-INTEGRAL\n");
    printf("3-MAX E MIN RELATIVOS\n");
    printf("4-EXTREMOS\n");
    printf("5-DOMINIO\n");
    printf("6-IMAGEM\n");
    printf("0-SAIR\n");
    opcao=input("Digite um numero:");
    if(opcao==0) then
        printf("\nVocê optou por sair do programa!");
end
end
```

Até agora consegui fazer funcionar a derivada polinomial, consigo extrair a derivada da expressão digitada. Gostaria de saber se existe alguma forma de fazer o mesmo com integral. Alguém pode me ajudar?

Já revirei a documentação toda praticamente e achei alguns comandos de integral como intg, etc. Porém esses não da para realizar integral com polinomios (tens que por o valor da variaveis). Se alguém tem alguma sugestão de função ou algum comando talvez que talvez possa me ajudar, eu agradeço!

**O esperado de entrada:**

`f(x)=2x²+4x`

**O esperado de saída:**

`x³ + 2x²`

Comment: A pessoa que me negativou poderia me explicar o que tem de errado na minha pergunta?

Comment: eu não entendo deste software e nem tanto assim de matemática para conseguir lhe ajudar, mas encontrei isto http://x-engineer.org/graduate-engineering/programming-languages/scilab/define-solve-polynomials-scilab/ e isto https://x-engineer.org/graduate-engineering/programming-languages/scilab/solve-definite-integral-scilab/, espero que ajude.

Comment: Obrigado @GuilhermeNascimento vou tentar ver!